# How to efficiently evaluate element in javascript array by using reduce function

Tags: javascript

I have an array called **people** which is an array of objects(*person's* name and his/her *city*'s name), and i want to make a function that calculate the total number of **distinct cities** in that array. I used a function that use for loop but it seems to be a better way by using reduce functions in javascript. Here is the snippet

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Jessica", city: "New York"},
  { name: "Steve",   city: "Los Angels"},
  { name: "Peter",   city: "Boston"},
  { name: "Elaine",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Chris",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Mike",  city: "Boston"},
  { name: "George",  city: "Vancouver"},
];
let nbre_distinct_cities = 0;

countDistinctCity(people);
console.log('Total number of distinct cities: ',nbre_distinct_cities); 

function countDistinctCity(people)
{
  for(let i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
  {
      if(i === people.length - 1)
      {
          break;
      }
      else if(people[i].city !== people[i + 1].city)
      {
        nbre_distinct_cities++
      }
  }

}
```

I would appreciate if someone suggest an efficient function using  *reduce()* function

Comment: What's the point of that first `if` statement? What if the last city in the list is unique?

Comment: @Pointy It's because the logic is wrong to avoid an index out of bounds. This logic doesn't count the unique entries. Consider using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: @Pointy. i use the if just to make sure i don't compare with undefined element. i compare previous element and next element of the array

Comment: In regards to your title and the last line of your question: `every()` certainly does not apply here. Check out [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). `reduce()` is closer, but you could probably just `.map()` the cities into a new `Set` and get its `size`.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider oh right, I see now. Yea this is just all wrong; a Set (or even a simple object since the city names are just strings) would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store all the cities from the array and, since a set only has unique entries, the final size of the set will give you the number of distinct cities:

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Jessica", city: "New York"},
  { name: "Steve",   city: "Los Angels"},
  { name: "Peter",   city: "Boston"},
  { name: "Elaine",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Chris",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Mike",  city: "Boston"},
  { name: "George",  city: "Vancouver"},
];

let nbre_distinct_cities = new Set(people.map(({city}) => city)).size;
console.log('Total number of distinct cities: ', nbre_distinct_cities);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce

```
Object.keys(people.reduce((acc, ppl) => (acc[ppl.city] = ppl.city, acc), {})).length
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the problem via reduce method

```
    const cities = people.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
       const isItNotExistInAccumulator
          = accumulator.every(city => city !== current.city);
       if (isItNotExistInAccumulator) return [current.city, ...accumulator];
       return accumulator;
    }, []);

    console.log(cities.length);
```

Comment: This would work but I'd suggest a simple `accumulator.indexOf(current.city) < 0` instead of using `.every()`, personally.

Comment: `accumulator.every` is O(n^2), looping repeatedly over the accumulator for each and every element. `Set` or object is O(n), with a constant time check for adding each element (and less verbose). `indexOf(current.city >= 0)` suffers from the same problems.

Comment: @ggorlen I wasn't arguing that this answer was better than the other - in fact I suggested the very same `Set` implementation in the comments above. Though, `indexOf` is at least more efficient than `.every()`, as it doesn't require the invocation of a callback method. I'm simply noting that using `.every()` to check if a string exists in an array is never a great choice.

Comment: It doesn't change the fundamental time complexity, which far outweighs any slight function call overhead between the two options, so it seems penny wise and pound foolish (feel free to benchmark the two, then benchmark both against the `Set` answer above to see what I mean, on a non-trivial number of elements).

Comment: @ggorlen Again, you seem to be debating something that we agree upon. I myself suggested the `Set` method in the comments on OP *before there were any answers*, because I agree - it is the best one, given its time complexity. However, I am telling Max that you should never use `.every()` to determine if a string exists in an array. I don't think this is the best answer regardless, but it's still a valuable takeaway.

Comment: Using `.every()` reimplements functionality found elsewhere. Using `.indexOf` would be preferable, or `.includes()` is better yet. Even using `.some()` would arguably be clearer than `.every()`.

Comment: Sure, if you want to talk about semantically meaningful method names purely, `.includes` is clearly the most appropriate among the "determine existence property of array" methods. My responses are geared towards informing the answerer why the accepted solution is better, and yours was also helpful but not the fundamental issue here. I'm not debating with you, just trying to communicate to the poster the most important issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that removes the duplicates with `Array.indexOf`

```js
const people = [
  { name: "Jessica", city: "New York"},
  { name: "Steve",   city: "Los Angels"},
  { name: "Peter",   city: "Boston"},
  { name: "Elaine",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Chris",  city: "Montreal"},
  { name: "Mike",  city: "Boston"},
  { name: "George",  city: "Vancouver"},
];

let nbre_distinct_cities = people.map(el => el.city)
 .filter((city, idx, arr) => arr.indexOf(city) === idx).length;

console.log('Total number of distinct cities: ', nbre_distinct_cities);
```